# For what values of $k$ will the equation $f (x) = k$ have no solutions?

Tags: trigonometry

If $f(x)= 4 \sin \left(3x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$

For what values of $k$ will the equation $f (x) = k$ have no solutions.

Comment: Could you figure it out if it were $g(x) = 4\sin(x)$ instead?

Comment: If $\lvert k\rvert > 4$, for a start. Can you see why?

Comment: not really... I am a little stuck with Trigonometry.... Why would K have no solutions when the absolute value of K is more than 4?

Comment: The $\sin$ function can only take values between $-1$ and $1$ (included). Multiplied by $4$, anything of the form $4\sin(\dots)$ can only be between $-4$ and $4$ (included).

Comment: Thank you very Much! all this time I was focusing on the X variable and on all the possibilities I had with X While ignoring the property of the sin function

Answer (score 1):

We always have that $$-1\leq \sin(x)\leq 1.$$ So we must also have $$-4\leq 4\sin (x)\leq 4.$$ Lastly, note that the whole of $\mathbb R$ is reached by $3x+\frac\pi2$. This means that the image of $f(x)=4\sin\left(3x+\frac\pi2\right)$ is exactly $[-4,4]$.

Hence $f(x)=k $ has no solution exactly when $\vert k\vert >4$.